# F# efficiency implications of passing large data structures between functions

Tags: performance, f#, pass-by-value

How does F# pass data from a caller function to a called function? Does it make a copy of the data before handing it over or does it just pass a pointer? I would think the latter but want to make sure. 
On a related note, are there any performance implications of the following 2 F# code styles.

```
let someFunction e =
    1//pretend this is a complicated function

let someOtherFunction e =
    2//pretend this is a complicated function

let foo f largeList=
    List.map (fun elem -> f elem)

let bar largeList =
    largeList
    |> foo someFunction
    |> foo someOtherFunction


let bar2 largeList =
    let foo2 f f2 =
        largeList
        |> List.map (fun elem -> f elem)
        |> List.map (fun elem -> f2 elem)
    foo2 someFunction someOtherFunction
```

Would you expect bar to have a different performance to bar2? If not, are there any situations I should be aware of that would make a difference?

Comment: structs are passed by value, classes by reference bar2 may be marginally faster but difference would be very small - just measure

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The short answer:**

No.  The entire list is not copied, just the reference to it is.

**The long answer:**

In F# (just like in C#) both value and reference types can be passed either by value or by reference.

Both value types and reference types are, by default, passed by value.

- In the case of value types (structs) this means that you'll be
  passing around a copy of the entire data structure.
- In the case of reference types (classes, discriminated unions, records, etc.) this means that *the reference* is passed by value.  This does not mean that the entire data structure is copied, it just means that an `int`/`int64` which references the data structure is copied.

If you're working with mutable data structures, e.g. `ResizeArray<'T>` (.NET `List<'T>`) which are classes, passing references by value could have implications.  Perhaps the function you've passed it to adds elements to the list, for example?  Such an update would apply to the data structure referenced from both locations.  Since your question uses the immutable F# List though, you don't have to worry about this!

You can also pass value/reference types by reference, for more detail about that see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx#Anchor_4

F# list is implemented as a singly linked list, that means that access the head and prepend operations are O(1).  These data structures are also very memory efficient because when you prepend an element to the list you only need to store the new value and a reference to the rest of the list.

So you can see how it works, such a data structure can be implemented like this:

```
type ExampleList<'T> = 
    |Empty
    |Cons of 'T * List<'T>
```

**Additional Information:**

`List.map` is eagerly evaluated meaning that every time you call it, a new list will be created.  If you use `Seq.map` (F# List implements the `IEnumerable<'T>` interface), which is lazily evaluated, you can evaluate both map operations in only enumeration of the list.

```
largeList
|> Seq.map (fun elem -> f elem)
|> Seq.map (fun elem -> f2 elem)
|> List.ofSeq
```

This is likely to be a lot more efficient for large lists because it involves allocating only one new list of results, rather than two.